# Change menu item text by ID

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have HMENU and id, but after change text of menu item:

```
ModifyMenu(optionsMenu, ID_MENUITEM, MF_BYCOMMAND, ID_MENUITEM, wsBuf);
```

I can't set check/uncheck on it

```
 MENUITEMINFO uncheckItem;
    uncheckItem.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    uncheckItem.fMask = MIIM_STATE;
    uncheckItem.fState = MFS_UNCHECKED;

    SetMenuItemInfo(optionsMenu, ID_MENUITEM, FALSE, &uncheckItem);
```

Any ides?

Comment: Both `ModifyMenu()` and `SetMenuItemInfo()` return FALSE if they fail. Is that actually happening? If so, then `GetLastError()` will tell you why they failed.

Comment: from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648001(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN article, you need to call [DrawMenuBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647633(v=vs.85).aspx) whenever a menu changes